# why do I have compile time error in my code

Tags: c

```
gradebook_t* read_gradebook_from_binary(const char* file_name) {
  struct student rec;
  char book_name[MAX_NAME_LEN];
  FILE* file = fopen(file_name, "rb");
  const char* token = strtok(file_name, ".");
  strcpy(book_name, token);
  gradebook_t* book = create_gradebook(book_name);
  if (!file) {
    printf("Unable to open file!");
    return NULL;
  }
  while (fread(&rec, sizeof(struct student), 1, file) != 0) {
    add_score(book, rec.name, rec.score);
  }
  fclose(file);
  return book;
}
```

I keep getting error that says:

```
passing argument 1 of 'strtok' discards 'const' qualifier from pointer target type [-Wdiscarded-qualifiers]
   const char * token = strtok(file_name, ".");
```

I am confused on the reason why I get this error and why my code wont compile.

Comment: strtok doesn't take a `const char*` - in fact it *mustn't* be const as it gets modified by strtok. And don't forget to thank your compiler for not letting you run this code.

Comment: `strtok` modifies the source parameter array, so the fact that file_name is `const` means that you can't modify it. Make a copy of it first if  you need to tokenize it.

Answer (score 1):

`file_name` is a pointer to constant chars.
`strtok` expects a pointer to non-const chars. It expects this because it will modify the string.